# MTS Mblaze not detecting in Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: internet, usb-modem, modem

My MTS Mblaze is not detecting in Ubuntu 12.04LTS. When i tried to install Mblaze driver it shows NDIS driver missing. 
Again tried commenting dkg line in code. Even though i'm not able to install my mblaze.

Please help.?

Answer (score 0):

connect your modem and wait for it to be detected and shown in the network connections notification panel.
connect it is using details :
phone number : #777
username : internet@internet.mtsindia.in
password : MTS
connect it. if gets connected then you're lucky otherwise restart your system keeping mblaze modem connected.
after restart, wait for mts mblaze to show up in the network connections notification panel, and connect it.
should connect successfully.